# D3 Optional Transitions

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

I have a D3 chart that transitions plot points. Sometimes I want these to be animated transitions, and sometimes I want them to be instantaneous. Is there a DRY way to do this kind of stuff in D3?

For example:

```
    svg.selectAll('g.data-point')
        .data(dataset)
        .transition()
        .duration(transitionTime)
        .attr({
            class: function(d) {
                return getClassesForPoint(d);
            },
            transform: function(d) {
                return ('translate(' + ((d.x) ? xScale(d.x) : xScale(0)) + ', ' + yScale(d.y) + ')');
            }
        });
```

If I only want to do the animated transition based on a condition, do I need to repeat that block without lines 3-4 via an if-else structure, or is there a better way to do that? The chaining is throwing me a bit. I've already tried giving it a duration of 0 and it still goes through the animation engine.

Any thoughts?

### EDIT:

Turns out my selector was defunct and, as Lars mentioned, using duration(0) works fine. However, I have come across this kind of situation a couple of different times, where it seems like there's enough commonality in two chains, but I can't figure out how to properly or dynamically add / remove calls to the chain.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your concern about using `duration(0)` -- it should give you the same behaviour as having no transition, no?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff technically that's not correct - the appearance will be the same however it'll shift the code to be asynchronous. That's normally OK but a bit of a pain for testing.

Answer (score 3):

Since the [`transition` object](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions) supports *most* of the methods supported by the [`selection` object](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections) (except functions like `append`), you can conditionally choose one of those to operate on:

```
var selection = svg.selectAll('g.data-point').data(dataset).enter();
if (condition) { selection = selection.transition().duration(transitionTime); }
selection.attr(/* .. */);
```

Comment: That's quite elegant, but I suspect that it's prone to causing unexpected problems later on, especially for somebody who doesn't know your code.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [.call](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-call):

```
function transformationAndSetClass(selection){
   selection.attr({
        class: function(d) {
            return getClassesForPoint(d);
        },
        transform: function(d) {
            return ('translate(' + xScale(d.x ? d.x : 0) + ', ' + yScale(d.y) + ')');
        }
    });
}
```

Then, when you need to reuse those lines of code:

```
svg.selectAll('g.data-point')
    .data(dataset)
    .transition()
    .duration(transitionTime)
    .call(transformationAndSetClass)
```

Comment: Your function is missing a close bracket.  Otherwise, this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can use the .each() method paired with d3.select(this) to have more fine-grained control of your selection:

```
 svg.selectAll('g.data-point')
    .data(dataset)
    .each(function (d) {
      if (d.someCondition == "something") {
        d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("transform", "translate(100,100)
      }
      else {
        d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(100,100)
      }

 })
```

Obviously, it's a bit more verbose.